# Spring @Repository annotation meaning

Tags: spring

I was going through Spring Dao tutorials. I have seen `@Repository` annotation in *DaoImplementation* class.
I understood that all the database access logic should be written over here. However I could not understand
the below point.

1. what does spring do when `@Repository` is found? I got the below sentence from the Spring doc.
   A class thus annotated is eligible for Spring *DataAccessException* translation. So what is the meaning of this?
   Can anyone give me an example?
2. If `@Repository` is declared, `@Autowire` should be done along with this?
   Does spring automatically inject the sessionfactory to this class?

Answer (score 0):

1. what does spring do when @Repository is found? I got the below sentence from the Spring doc. A class thus annotated is eligible for Spring DataAccessException translation. So what is the meaning of this? Can anyone give me an example?

Spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) says

> > @Repository annotation is a marker for any class that fulfills the role or stereotype (also known as Data Access Object or DAO) of a repository. Among the uses of this marker is the automatic translation of exceptions.
> >
> > When you use Hibernate, JPA, or JDO in a DAO, you must decide how to handle the persistence technology's native exception classes. The DAO throws a subclass of a HibernateException, PersistenceException or JDOException depending on the technology. These exceptions are all run-time exceptions and do not have to be declared or caught. You may also have to deal with IllegalArgumentException and IllegalStateException. This means that callers can only treat exceptions as generally fatal, unless they want to depend on the persistence technology's own exception structure. Catching specific causes such as an optimistic locking failure is not possible without tying the caller to the implementation strategy. This trade off might be acceptable to applications that are strongly ORM-based and/or do not need any special exception treatment. However, Spring enables exception translation to be applied transparently through the @Repository annotation:

2. If @Repository is declared, @Autowire should be done along with this? Does spring automatically inject the sessionfactory to this class?

   > > Spring doesn't automatically inject the SessionFactory, unless you declare it as autowiring bean or your DAO derived from `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`
   > >
   > > It's not mandatory that every `@Repository` must be declared with `@Autowired` sessionFactory, you can have your own singleton implementation for instantiating `SessionFactory` and take a control of injecting it. But it's not recommended.